# WordPress blog to Blogger for auto post through IFTTT

Tags: wordpress, if-this-then-that

I have connected my WordPress blog to Blogger for auto post through IFTTT. Now I want to connect my another WordPress blog to my Blogger blog for auto post. How can I add my second WordPress blog in IFTTT?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no, because you can only configure one WordPress blog in the [WordPress channel](https://ifttt.com/wordpress).

An alternative is to use a different channel, such as the [Feed](https://ifttt.com/feed) channel to pick up new posts from your other blog to send to your Blogger channel.

You might be able to do what you want with another IFTTT account.